# Uploaded images are not displayed in forwarded jsp until I refresh the page in javaEE?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, java-ee-7

I am working on a project where during filling form user has to upload an image, after saving form details in the database I am forwarding to jsp to display the image, but it does not show until I continously refresh the page for 2 or 3 times.

How can I resolve this issue?
[project hierarchy is displayed in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEGu6.png)

This is the path where I am saving my uploaded images:

bookPicPath
/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.58/webapps/library-management/src/main/webapp/assets

This is the code for getting displaying images in jsp:

```
<div class="book-box">
    <img alt="${book.title }" src="${'assets' += File.separator += book.picPath}"><br>
    <a href="<c:url value="book">
        <c:param name="action" value="view"/>
        <c:param name="ISBN" value="${book.ISBN }"/> </c:url> " class="book-title"><i>${book.title }</i>
        </a>
</div>
```

The question is that image is uploaded successfully, but display takes time, untill I refresh the page two or three times.
Here is the output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wYyx.png)

Comment: Please create a separate question for the second topic (where to store resources). This is not a discussion forum and not suitable for answering multiple things at once. And regarding the first topic: please provide a minimal reproducible example, or at least show all the relevant code and the additional debugging information such as the Chrome inspector network log. At the moment there is insufficient information to help you.

Comment: Thank you brother, I have removed the second part of my question.

Comment: How is your development setup? Are you running the web application directly from an IDE? Or are you creating a .jar/.war file and deploying it? Or do you directly edit .jsp files in /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.58? And does the browser display any error (in the console of the inspector) when the page is loaded without image?

Comment: @Codo I am running application directly from IDE in browser, when I add a book with an image after successful addition of book I redirect user to display jsp, when user reaches to display jsp he can see other details of the book, except for the image, but when after 1 or 2sec he refreshes the page he can then he can see the image. I am uploading the output image in the question. As you can see that the previously uploaded images are visible except for newly added book which is 'Eloquent javascript'.

Comment: It seems you haven't separated the development from the run-time environment. From what it looks, the uploaded image is saved in the source directory. There it will be detected sooner or later by the IDE (as if you had made a change to the source code). It then copies it over to the run-time environment. If so, use another directory for storing the images. Do not mix it with images in the source directory.